# Is it an acceptable pattern for an init method to return an object of a different type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm working on bugfixes for some existing objective-c code and came across something I thought strange:

```
@interface ClassA : UIView
...

static ClassA* oldSelf = nil;

@implementation
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    oldSelf = self;
    self = [[ClassB alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame]; // xcode warns: Incompatible pointer types assigning to "ClassA *" from "ClassB *"
    //       ^^^^^^ Is this ok?
    [oldSelf release];
    return self;
}


@interface ClassB : UIView
...

@implementation
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}
```

This whole thing is wrapped up into a **static library**.  The public gets the lib.a file and ClassA.h
In code using the library, This occurs:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

...

// useage
ClassA *myA = [[ClassA alloc] initiWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
...
```

So we got an initializer for ClassA that actually returns an unrelated class.  ClassA and ClassB respond to the same messages so it compiles and runs.  Seems like ClassA is being used to  obscure some features exposed in ClassB?

I'm curious if this is acceptable behavior, and if it's a known pattern, what is it called?  Are there any side effects to this setup?

=========================================================

Thanks for everyone's answers!  I think I've got it...  in short, not a normal pattern, and not exactly a good idea

- Kind of like a "class cluster"(abstract factory), but not quite, because a common abstract class should be returned.  And since the code doesn't seem to ever intend to return anything but a ClassB object, probably not what the original author was thinking.
- More like a proxy, but implemented wrong.  ClassA should hold a private instance of ClassB and pass messages between the two.

=========================================================

Edited: added "oldSelf" parts...

Edited: added static library details...

Edited: added a blurb about the accepted answer...

Comment: Does `ClassA`'s `initWithFrame:` have `[self release]` before the assignment to `self`?

Comment: Not acceptable on the grounds that it is misleading.

Comment: @josh yes it does. As a ObjC n00b, I wasn't sure that detail was relevant so I left it out.  The concern is about leaks?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, exactly. At that point, `self` points to an allocated (though not set up) instance, and needs to be released if the pointer's going to be reassigned. The static pointer `oldSelf` seems strange to me, though -- a local variable would work just as well. Do you have access to the person who wrote this code, to ask for clarification about the set up here?

Comment: @josh I agree, the static oldSelf variable is quite strange. The code was written by an offshore consultant, I'll have to do some digging to see if he still exists :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major disadvantage I see here is: a user of `ClassA` would expect that an object he just created via `[[ClassA alloc] initWithFrame:...]` returns YES for `[object isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]`.
This might also lead to errors when using things like `NSInvocation`, because the wrong class would be used to determine the method signature, though I am not sure about that.

Due to Objective-Cs dynamic nature, this will, as you described, work, but may be confusing to use and i would strongly discourage anyone from using this pattern.

As pilavdzice said, the *"right"* alternative to this would be to have both `ClassA`and `ClassB` inherit from another class (an **abstact superclass**) which then in its initializer decides what **concrete subclass** to use. Good examples of this pattern, called class clusters, are `NSString`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` which all return objects of various subclasses based on how you initialize them, which is also the reason you can not subclass those directly without some effort.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an unreasonable thing to do in all cases, but it's hard to say whether it's a good idea in the situation you describe. Two examples where it might be fine:

- The initializer returns an instance of a more specialized subclass. For example, you might choose different implementations of a data structure depending on the number of items being stored.
- The initializer returns some sort of proxy object.

Your code does seem a bit odd. At the very least, I'd expect to see a cast as a signal (both to the compiler and to future programmers) that the author knew what he was doing. A comment explaining the reason for returning a different type of object wouldn't hurt, either. Ideally, `ClassB` should be a subclass of `ClassA` since it's expected to provide the same interface.

Comment: Good points.  It is reminiscent of an abstract factory/proxy.  The fact that there are no comments or casting, to me, hints that someone didn't intend this behavior, or didn't quite know what they were doing(I say this with humility, being myself very green in ObjC).

Answer (score 2):

Class clusters are implemented in this way, sort-of.  A related technique, `isa`-swizzling can be used to implement a sort of state machine.  It does require the same ivar layout to work.  In terms of side effects, I believe that it may break KVO; but someone may correct me on that point.

Comment: "Sort of" is putting it mildly. A true class cluster would have `ClassB` inheriting from `ClassA`. This seems quite weird to me.

Comment: True, I was stretching to find some design pattern to which this code was reminiscent...

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not common in user code to return an unrelated class, however it is common in some of Apple's frameworks to return a more specific version of a class with the same public interface.

Apple's  [Cocoa Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html) discusses in some amount of detail the fact that objects such as NSArray and NSNumber may return a different object than the class you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a pattern I know of.

If I am understanding this correctly, the normal way to do this would be to have both classes inherit from the same abstract base class.

Answer (score 0):

As @alan duncun notes, this technique is called a class cluster and is somewhat common. But your implementation is slightly incorrect. You should never return a incompatible type. In your example, ClassB should inherit from ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is somewhat how [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is implemented.

This way the inner class is not exposed and can not be misused. ClassB can not be initialized somewhere else other than in the implementation file of ClassA.

This makes sense if you have multiple inner classes and your initializer somehow decides which class is actually needed.

I don't see any advantages if you only use one inner class.